# Why does a package have "Mixed" status in TeX Live Utility and how do I fix this?

Tags: packages, macos, tex-live-utility

I have updated my TeX Live Utility to version 1.49 and updated my packages. I'm running MacOS version 11.4

I updated the packages after updating TeX Live Utility. But some are showing a status of "Mixed", screenshot below. I tried to reinstall individually, but there was no change in status. I can't find out what "Mixed" means, and I assume it is not good.

My Latex package was/is closed during this process, so no packages should have been in use.

What should I do about changing the status? Or should I not worry about this?

[image: Screenshot showing two packages with mixed status]

Answer (score 2):

Typically, package that have “Mixed” status contain binaries and `tlmgr` by default only installs the binaries proper for the platform it's run on.

`fig4latex` and `findhyph` are in this class.

Don't worry, it's not “bad”.

Comment: If you click on the > it will show you all the binary versions and the one installed.